# Switch from Beta Version to Stable Version

Tags: wordpress-version

I am currently running a WordPress Beta Version on a new site I'm testing. Now, it's about time to go live and I was wondering what should I do in order to get back to the stable version of WordPress? I'm trying to avoid the re-installation process all over again if possible.

If I stick to this beta release for now and delete the [Beta Tester Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-beta-tester/), can I upgrade to the most stable version of WordPress when it hits the release? Is anything else I should worry about?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your environment, you could backup all your core files (given you haven't hacked them) and the DB. It's also a good idea to backup your beta. Next, switch over - if it's production to live for client / public, do it during a time that traffic is lowest, assuming you track your traffic.

Release the beta site at the domain (depending on your environment you might need to sterilize the DB and change URL paths) - if it fails, revert using your backup. If all goes well, the transition should be without issue upon upgrade.