# Production Site: Moving from WordPress RC to Final Release Version

Tags: wordpress-version

Although it's not recommended, I'm planning to use the 4.4RC for a new production site (the new Twentysixteen theme is perfect for what I need). Once the final release version is out, what is the process for updating? Is it a simple core update? Do I need to do something different? If so, what?

Would it be better to use the Beta Test plugin?

The only relevant question had no answer.

[Switch from Beta Version to Stable Version](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70921/switch-from-beta-to-stable-workaround)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend checking out the beta-tester plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-beta-tester/

[image: WordPress Beta Tester Plugin]

It gives you an easy way to check it out, and switching back to stable with it is simple from the interface by clicking "Re-install Now"

It will allow you to upgrade to the latest releases.  It's good to get a jump start on dev, but I would also say it's a good idea to stick on stable once 4.4 comes out for the production side of things ( target date Dec. 8, 2015).